# How to construct matrix based on condition and position?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix A=

```
np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I wanna build a matrix B where B[i,j]=5 if A[i,j]=1 and (i+1)%3=0; B[i,j]=0 otherwise.

The B should be: B=

```
np.matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 5, 0, 0]]
```

Is there any possible method to achieve this without using for loop, just like matrix calculation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I have not thought of a way to eliminate the for-loop in the list comprehension for filtering on the remainder condition, but the "heavy" part of the computation exploits numpy's optimizations.

```
import numpy as np
newdata = 5 * np.array([(i + 1) % 3 == 0 for i in range(data.shape[-1])]) * np.array(data)
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER (prior to condition that for-loops cannot be used):

Assuming your matrix is stored as `data`, then you can use list comprehension syntax to get what you want.

```
newdata = [[5 if val == 1 and (idx + 1) % 3 == 0 else 0
            for idx, val in enumerate(row)]
           for row in data]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can we do it not using for loop/

Comment: I will think on it. In the meantime, would you mind adding the following details to your question? (1) Why must it be without a for loop? (Because looping must occur whether its implicit or explicit). (2) What is the type of your data? (Originally, I looked and thought it was as list of lists, but now I realize it's probably a numpy matrix.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have added more details to my question. The reason why I don't want a loop is that matrix calculation is somewhat faster than a loop.